# Incremental Update statement in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, sql-update

Is there any way to update in the way that every time my Update stmt check for the max(column) value and then +1 and update the record. For example.

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET NEW_KEY = (SELECT MAX(KEY) + 1 FROM MyTable)
WHERE NEW_RECORD = 0;
```

So instead of just picking max and then set max+1 for all the records. It do it in iterations, by looking max value every time.

Comment: You might want to put in some more details, because I'm concerned you aren't doing this safely (ie, multiple processes might give you duplicate ids).  Do you not have an auto-generated id?  Note that safely continuing in this fashion will require you to lock the table (at least during this statement, if not for a while longer in the transaction), which will absolutely _kill_ concurrency.

Comment: It is safe you don't worry about it. It is on a test table. And I've all the precautions for duplication. Once again its on test table so my data will be safe and intact.

Comment: ...so then why isn't this statement itself sufficient?

Comment: Currently I have 0 in the NEW_KEY. This stmt pick the max value. For instance 200 is the max it will pick this value adds 1 into it. And will update with 201 everywhere, where criteria is matched. But I want a series 201, 202, 203, 204 for every next record.

Comment: Do you have multiple records or only one?  What version/platform of DB2?  Give starting data and desired results.

Comment: DB2 LUW, Yes multiple.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse No more questions? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in one statement:

```
UPDATE (SELECT new_key, new_record,
               MAX(key) OVER(ORDER BY key) as minimumKey,
               COUNT() OVER(ORDER BY key ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) + 1 as offsetKey
        FROM MyTable) MyTable
SET new_key = minimumKey + offsetKey
WHERE new_record = 0;
```

(untested, because I don't have an LUW instance to use)
If there are rows with `new_record <> 0`, there will be gaps in the sequence of the new keys (my personal belief is that the actual value of a key is unimportant, so don't worry about that).

Comment: SQL Error [42601]: An unexpected token "UNBOUNDED" was found following "ER BY CIRATS_DIM_KEY".  Expected tokens may include:  "CONCAT".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.16.53
  An unexpected token "UNBOUNDED" was found following "ER BY KEY".  Expected tokens may include:  "CONCAT".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.16.53

Comment: Looks like `ROWS` was also needed (I think - I've never used these features before, _but I know how to read documentation_).

Comment: SQL Error [42601]: An unexpected token "PROCEEDING" was found following "M_KEY ROWS UNBOUNDED".  Expected tokens may include:  "PRECEDING".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.16.53
  An unexpected token "PROCEEDING" was found following "M_KEY ROWS UNBOUNDED".  Expected tokens may include:  "PRECEDING".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.16.53


Can you please provide me the link you are looking at from documentation. So that I can follow along. Instead of ping you for the errors. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Whups, `PRECEDING` not `PROCEEDING` (...stupid English language).  [You don't have a link to the relevant documentation saved](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0023461.html) or **can't google for it**?

Comment: I have it opened in front of me but I wasn't on the right page. Thanks a lot anyways. It works perfectly. I also edit your answer. Thanks for your help. It will be great if I can have you somewhere in my contacts. Facebook etc ?

Comment: Your edit was not correct - If the max-key row was where `new_record <> 0`, you wouldn't get it.  Why did you think it wasn't visible (if that was the case, none of the others would be either)?

Comment: In update statement we are providing it a criteria instead of the table name and it is bounded between the braces. So that column name is out of the scope and not visible to DB. So that it gives an error that NEW_RECORD is unknown.

Comment: And yes where new_record <> 0, I will not get it and this is the desired solution in my problem. So it is working perfect. Thanks :)

Comment: @Superman: Stop editing the answer – to discuss changes please use the comment function.